# Is there a faster way of character animation other than by hand?

Tags: animation

Okay to start I have been doing blender for about 1 year (On and off). I want to understand if there is a faster way of doing animations other than hand doing it.

My conundrum is that I can get a [Mixamo](https://www.mixamo.com/#/) animation and retarget it on my rig. But the frames fit the Mixamo animation and not in the frames that I want. Also the mesh gets messed up when I do it.

I don't have too much time where I can hand do it but I don't want to retarget the animation if it gets messed up. I need a solution on animating basic movements fast. FYI I did think about motion capture, its too expensive.

Comment: I'm fairly new to Blender, but I've been doing animation for quite a while now. I'd like to try to help until someone else pops in. When you talk about the Mixamo animations not matching the frames that you want - are you talking about the timing of the animation?

Comment: i don't know what your experience level with blender is...but a good rig offers a lot of possibilities to make the animation easier e.g. IK. Or drivers. Poles. And i am pretty sure your problem with the frames to fit mixamo animation can be solved - unfortunately i am not a pro rigger so i cannot help you here.

Comment: Can you add some example of your specific issue (blend, screens) so we can understand what are you trying to solve?